# How to improve the performance of java web application

Tags: java, ajax, performance

The problem is at the first time, loading of the pages is taking more amount to time and I want to reduce the loading time.
Actually, in jsp there is 5 radio button, where onclick of each button data will load from database.
Technically, controller call the dao,in dao a function is calling 5 procedure which is related to each radio button.

So, I m planing to to use listener, or ajax which will be fine, or is there any other better option to improve performance, then how to implement.

Comment: measure twice, cut once. First find out where the actual problem is, then think about what should be done about it.

Comment: Paste your website link or test it with browser plugins first.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to work out where the time goes.

Is it in your javascript, in the network, in your DAO classes or in the database?

The solution will depend on the exact nature of the problem, the most likely culprits are the network and/or your DOA classes making inefficient use of the database (polite way of saying crap SQL :-) ).

You could try sending down the data for the first (default) radio button with the initial request, to give the user the impression of more responsive system.

Comment: thanks James, javascript is not doing any problem, it is db call bcoz when dat dao function is loading, it call procedure 5 time, which is increasing the loading time.

Comment: i m thinking of loading the db from Listener class,will dat be fine

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right the time is getting consumed in your procedures. if your stored procedures are taking time, better use callback with your ajax.

Again it depends if user can interact with other features in your web app during the wait time else callbacks don't make sense.

You have to decide your design based on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to prevent more calls.

**for radio button things**
See if u can reduce the function calls.(**merge function/use more conditions**) its more time consuming to run ur funtions probably...

Answer (score 0):

"controller call the dao,in dao a function is calling 5 procedure which is related to each radio button." That sounds like a possible 5 threads running those process, in case of course that those process don't block each others. An investigation about that is necessary first.

In case of no blocking or other possible concurrency issues, I recommend you to use Future http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Every single future will start in a new thread and once it finish will invoke a callback. So as soon as your 5 process will finish you can render the view.This 5 process working on paralel will give you 5 times faster global process.

Comment: "5 process working on paralel will give you 5 times faster process" is just not true. Recommending blindly that multithreading will solve his problem (and with 5 times the speed too) is just completely unfounded.

Comment: @Kayaman  Sorry but if instead you do a sequential 5 process process you do those 5 process on parallel you´re not making faster the whole process?.  What I missing here guys?!?!

Comment: You're misunderstanding how multithreading works and making a naive assumption that more threads automatically mean more speed. Just because you need to do 5 things doesn't mean that they can be parallelized. Not to mention that if you have let's say 10 simultaneous users creating 5 threads each, you'll have 50 threads and the processor only has so many cores.

Comment: I´v been working with multithreading a lot of years, and always has been useful on parallel processor that CAN be executed on parallel. Do you understand that a JVM can create more than 1000 threads per SO right?. Of course the number of Cores it´s limited but  again, please, response this to you. Do 5 process in parallel that dont have any lock each other is not faster than do sequentially?. Why do you think Java introduce Futures?.  Please dont try to apply your dogmas to everybody, not all people think and work with your ideas.  Discussion is over anyway, thanks for the negative point ;)

Comment: You don't decide when the discussion is over. You were making a blanket statement "parallelize it, that'll make it faster" when that's clearly wrong. I'm amazed that you would say something like this if indeed you've been working with multithreading for "a lot of years". You have no idea if the work he's doing is CPU bound, database bound, network bound or whatever. Either you've always managed to work with extremely simple cases, or you don't really understand how multithreading works. The correct answer as given by James above is "identify hotspots" **then** you can consider multithreading.

Comment: Of course depends on what you´re process are doing, dont you read me before?. "has been useful on parallel processor that CAN be executed on parallel", when I say Can be executed on parallel of course I investigate that it wont have any CPU bottleneck impact, or possible deadlock or whatever other possible issue that concurrency can brings. But hey!, I must be crazy for just consider the possibility of use multithreading here!.

Comment: And the answer of James, that you consider correct, suggest to return the first process to the client and do the rest on parallel to give the user the feedback that the process is done, oh my god is using multithreading!!!. Dont forget to put him a negative point pal.

Comment: I'm not sure if English is your first language (it isn't mine), but I just didn't parse "always has been useful on parallel processor that CAN be executed on parallel." as you probably meant it. As for James' answer, there's no reason to downvote it. He said 1) Investigate 2) If the problem is database bound, return data with ajax for more responsiveness. There's no need to get angry, it's just SO, and sometimes you get downvoted. Usually for a reason, sometimes not necessarily (or at least in your own opinion).

Comment: I´m not getting mad, it´s just that I fight for my convictions and you fight for yours. I update my ticket to make it a little bit more clear, but still, I consider that multithreading it´s a very useful tool, of course to be used properly.

Comment: I removed the downvote, not so much because of the edit, but because the other answers aren't that great either, and because I don't want to waste any more time on this.